# Logback file with timestamp in file name not rolledover

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic

I am using below configuration for logs. File is not rolled over when timestamp is included in the file name. Is this because of timeReference used in timestamp? If I remove timestamp from file name then file rolls on reaching 10KB file size.

Is there any way to include timestamp in file name and at the same time make rollover working?

```
<timestamp key="startTime" datePattern="yyyyMMdd_HHmmss" timeReference="contextBirth">
<property name="logFileName" value="xyz_${startTime}">
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${logFileName}.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${logFileName}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10KB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date %level %logger{35} %msg%n%rEx</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue. There were 2 appenders with same file name. So rename was failing.

Below description on https://logback.qos.ch/codes.html site helped me.

> File/FileNamePattern option has the same value "..." as that given for
>   appender [...] defined earlier.
>
> If a FileAppender/RollingFileAppender defined earlier has the same
>   File option as the current appender, then those two appenders are in
>   collision as FileAppender instances cannot share the same output
>   target. To prevent loss of data, the current appender will not start.
>   Make sure that each appender has a unique File option.
>
> By analogy the same restriction applies to the FileNamePattern option
>   of RollingFileAppender. Make sure that each RollingFileAppender has a
>   unique FileNamePattern option